# React.js on Rails Order Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

how i can show my array in order ASC or DESC an example.

here is my react component

```
var News = React.createClass({

 displayName: 'News',

  render: function() {
    return (
           <div>
             <div>
             <h4>{this.props.news.title}</h4></div>
             <div>{this.props.news.created_at}</div>
             <div>{this.props.news.body}</div>


           </div>
    );
   }
 });
```

and here is my render

```
<% @news.each do |news|  %>
                <%= react_component('News', { :news => news }) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order the news in your controller 
`@news = News.all.order(created_at: :asc)`

`:asc` can be swapped out for `:desc`.

Try to not modify the data from react, but only present it.